# Which is better, multiple requests for multiple files or single request for a single file S3?

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, dataframe, amazon-s3

I have a 10gb CSV file. I can put the file in S3 in 2 ways.

1) Upload the entire file into single csv object.

2) Divide the file into multiple chunks(say 200mb) and upload.

Now I need to get all the data in the object into a pandas data frame which is running on a EC2 instance.

1) One way is to make a single request and get the file, if it is to be a one big file and put the data in dataframe.

2) Other way is to make multiple requests for each object and keep appending data to dataframe.

Which is the better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

With multiple files, you will have possibility to download them simultaneously in parallel threads. But this has 2 drawbacks:

1. These operations are IO heavy (network mostly), so depending on your instance type you might have worse performance overall
2. Multithreaded apps include some overhead in handling errors, aggregating results and such.

Depending on what you do, you might also want to look at AWS Athena, which can query data in S3 for you and produce results in seconds, so you don't have to download it at all.

Comment: Ya I checked Athena, but it is mostly used for adhoc querying. In my case, I get the data into data frame perform multiple operations and again need to store in another S3 bucket.